# Почему два раза выполняется событие клика?

Tags: jquery, javascript

**Js code:**

```
$(document).on("click", '.deleteProfilephoto', function() { alert('dd');
        return false;
    });
```

**Клик по элементу:**

```
<div class="deleteProfilephoto"><div class="profile_photo_hide"></div></div>
```

Нужно заметить, что блок **.deleteProfilephoto** подгружается на страницу Ajax'ом и по клику вызывается два раза **alert();**

Comment: Скрипт часом второй раз не подгружается через аякс?

Comment: Проверил - нет, подгружается только контент HTML. Может быть, дело в $(document).on?